# Should this be a bug or not - ASP.NET Request parameter

Tags: asp.net, textbox, request, postback

I posted a number of bugs on Microsoft site and while they were real bugs, MSFT will close it as design [And I figured most people favour MSFT anyways]. Here is one that I am sure they will clasify as by design but to me this is a serious bug.

This is all I have in ASPX page (NET 3.5).

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>        
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" /><br />

<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  /* this works  */
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            string txt = string.Empty;

            txt = Request.Params["TextBox1"];

            lblOutput.Text = "You entered : " + txt;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { /* this does not */
            string txt = string.Empty;

            txt = Request.Params["TextBox1"];

            lblOutput.Text = "You entered : " + txt;

    }
```

Now if you include another simple HTML textbox (Not ASP) like this

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" name="mytextbox" /> // still it below the existing one
txt = Request.Params["mytextbox"]; // change to this line instead of TextBox1
```

Then it works in both places.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ /* Now this works which is weird but it does */
   If(IsPostback)
    {
        string txt = string.Empty;

        txt = Request.Params["TextBox1"];

        lblOutput.Text = "You entered : " + txt;
   }
}
```

I therefore should close the question.

Answer (score 0):

That is really fundamental stuff you're doing in that example, so I highly doubt it's a bug. From the example, it looks like you're going against the grain:

**Markup**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" />
    ...
</asp:PlaceHolder>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" /><br />  
<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox txtCtrl in PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        //append the textbox value to the label
        lblOutput.Text += String.Format("{0}<br/>", txtCtrl.Text);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<TextBox> txtList = PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();

    for (int ctrlIndex = 0; ctrlIndex < txtList.Count; ctrlIndex++)
    {
        TextBox txtCtrl = txtList.ElementAt(ctrlIndex);
        if (txtCtrl != null)
        {
            lblOutput.Text += String.Format("{0}<br/>", txtCtrl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was just a test case. My actual program has about 30 parameters and I am looping through all using Request.Param['label1], label2, and so on. While I got it working in test code, in actuall code it still does not work but a regular textbox does work! For me ASP just make things incredibly complicated while it is really simple stuff.

Comment: Again I am working with existing code so want to use it as it is but my above code pretty much explain what this bug is. Previous programer used regular textbox prob because he new asp textboxes creates problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the request object. The framework has already done all of the hard work so you won't have to. No offense to the previous programmer, but it sounds like he wasn't very fimiliar with ASP.NET. Looks like a classic ASP hybrid approach to me.

Comment: If you can come up with an approach where I can loop throgh 20 textbox values (TextBox1, TextBox2,..,TextBox20), that will solve the problem, preferebly in a loop, the way it is done because there are more field I am picking upto.

Comment: Ok I would probaly need something like this `for(int i=0:i<=20;i++){ string txt = ["Textbox"+i.ToString].Text `, I could not make this work for now. The reason I have other controls that in that particular group and I need to pick all. My loop is a general loop. About to leave though and can only check it later in the evening.

Comment: Do you know for sure that you'll have 20 inputs?

Comment: this is the way design is right now. Flexible is good but there are other textboxes on the page, just dont want to confuse it with them. I know it is not the best design, this is an older code.

Comment: With the markup I've provided the `PlaceHolder` serves as a container for that group of `TextBox` controls, so you don't need to worry about any controls outside of the `PlaceHolder`.

Comment: which header file do I need for `txtList.Controls.Count`, getting any error for TextBox List

Comment: What do you mean by "header file"? Is `txtList` the ID of your PlaceHolder?

Comment: error: `'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox>' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` I think an assembly reference is missing

Comment: I made it work in my test project by changing the line `txtList.Controls.Count` to `txtList.Count`. When I copy the code to my actual project, I get error for `OfType` and `ElementAt`. I tried adding different references but could not resolve it. That's why I say ASP.NET is very poorly written. This is not something I should be troubleshooting for one entire day.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2008, Windows XP. I made the sample code work but it does not work in actual project, I tried adding all the assembly that I could think of. In fact I added all the assemblies that were there in the sample project. A point to not, I am using a website project, not a VS Project, this how this application was built.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the project was using 3.5? You can check this under the application tab of the properties window.

Comment: Right click on website -> Properites -> Build (tab) -> Target Framework = .NET Framework 3.5. Other options are .NET Framework 3.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Make sure you've imported namespaces `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: Did that already :) Well I guess I will just leave it for now :) This is probably another bug I can file...lol

Comment: It is definitely something with your code. .NET isn't perfect, but they wouldn't have a product if they screwed basic stuff like this up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx#Y0) object instead normal `asp:*` controls, use it like this:

```
txt = Request["TextBox1"];
```

It will check all the `HttpRequest` collections.

> The QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collection member
>   specified in the key parameter. If the specified key is not found,
>   then null is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This did work in the example. --- but did not work in the actual code. Definitely a good tip.